# How to override SVG path fill with CSS?

Tags: css, svg

I have a small HTML file with an inline SVG object. There are a number of paths with default colorings as fills, and I'm trying to use CSS to override these fills without success. Below is my full project, including HTML, JS, SVG, and SSS.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
        <title>OMIX Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>OMIX MAP</h1>
        <div id="map">
            <object id="map-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/map.svg" onload="loadSVG()"></object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Get all elements of class 'metabolite' of a document.
getMetabolite = function(doc) {
    var metabolite = doc.querySelectorAll('g.Metabolite');
    return metabolite;
}

// Set event listener to array of 'metabolite' elements.
setEventListenerMetabolite = function(metabolite) {
    metabolite.forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
            this.classList.toggle('metabolite_hover');
        });
        element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            this.classList.toggle('metabolite_hover');
        });
    });
}

// Get elements of SVG on load.
loadSVG = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("map-svg");
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var metabolite = getMetabolite(svgDoc);
    var reaction = getReaction(svgDoc);

    setEventListenerMetabolite(metabolite);
}
```

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:omix="http://www.omix.bio/xsd/omixsvg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="tiny" height="2541" version="1.2" width="2298" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Network 'Homo sapiens'</title>
  <desc>Created with Omix</desc>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath1">
      <path d="M0,0 L2298.591,0 L2298.591,2541.682 L0,2541.682 L0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="7.5px" font-style="normal" font-weight="400" id="ID3f9bfff0" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1">
    <g class="Metabolite" id="Metabolite$NADH$3" name="NADH" omix:clone="3">
      <g class="Shape" id="Shape_of_Metabolite$NADH$3">
        <path d="M-30,-15 C-30,-17.761 -27.851,-20 -25.2,-20 L25.2,-20 C27.851,-20 30,-17.761 30,-15 L30,15 C30,17.761 27.851,20 25.2,20 L-25.2,20 C-27.851,20 -30,17.761 -30,15 L-30,-15" fill="#a28dff" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" id="ID3f089e5e" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1206.0929206118517,898.2429901388446)" vector-effect="none"/>
      </g>
      <g class="Label" id="Label_of_Metabolite$NADH$3">
        <text fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="18px" font-style="normal" font-weight="700" id="ID4037e797" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1173.6866706118517,883.2429901388446)" x="4.812" xml:space="preserve" y="22">NADH</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.metabolite_hover .Shape path {
    fill: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

I want to change the color of the path when hovering on an SVG object. My JS successfully changes the object class to include .metabolite_hover, however, the CSS isn't overriding the fill.

Comment: share your full SVG

Comment: maybe you need to change the colour of  `stroke="#000000"`

Comment: I updated with my full project @TemaniAfif

Comment: you need to put the <link> element to the stylesheet in the SVG file, not in the HTML file.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Is there a way to dynamically insert the stylesheet into the SVG using JS so that I don't need to manually edit the SVG? Or would that be too complicated?